# Formik / Yup not working (Unable to resolve module)

Tags: react-native, npm, yup

Hello guys so i tried to use formik / yup in my code but even after i installed it its not working and it says Unable to resolve modulefrom D:\Programing..... yup could not be found within the project or in these directories:

maybe i installed it wrong ? can you guys show me a better way for npm installation ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import {Formik} from 'formik';

const uploadPostSchema =Yup.object({
    imageUrl:Yup.string().url.required('Url is required'),
    caption:Yup.string().max(2200,'Caption has reached the max character')
})


const PostAdding =()=>{
    return(
         <Text style={{color:'white'}}>YOOO</Text>
    )
}

export default PostAdding;
```

Comment: yarn add is another way to install node dependencies.  yarn add formik and  yarn add yup

Comment: @Zaki have you found a fix? I am getting the same issue . `const Yup = require("yup")` is working though. Yup is not recognized as a module.

Answer (score 5):

Had similar issue, had to install the previous version of Yup.

npm uninstall yup

npm i yup@0.28.5